# Design issue with the webpage when using addthis share buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, webforms, addthis

I am working on a multilingual website which has english & arabic version.

Article shown in english version come up right but when article is viewed in arabic version it add lots of extra space on the left side. You can notice this by looking at the horizontal scroll bar at bottom of the browser. I am not able to figure out what is causing it. I would appreciate help regarding this. Below is the link for the browser

http://tinyurl.com/83s8n97

Website is designed in asp.net 4.0 webforms.

When i remove this script/HTML Code from page then page comes-up right in the center without any extra space on either side

```
<div style="width:100%;">                                      
<div class="addthissharewrapper">                                              
     <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="width:102px;">
              <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
               <a class="addthis_button_twitter"  ></a>
               <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
               <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-ddddddd"></script>
```

Comment: Your url points to a localhost. We can't see it.

Comment: @Andrew: My Apologies i fixed the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clear this:-

You are using two different Article IDs for same the article.
For English you are using:

```
http://tinyurl.com/cq7fv4n
```

and for Arabic you are using:

```
http://tinyurl.com/83s8n97
```

Now please check this; I find out that the problem is here:

- There is a class `.at_a11y` in `widget082.css` (line 1);
  if we remove `[left: -10000px !important;]` from class `[at_a11y]` then the horizontal scroll can be removed.

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I am using the same physical page "ArticleDetails.aspx" but different CSS to display English & Arabic contents. Problem only appears in arabic version. English version comes up right. In order to troubleshoot this issue i even removed the Arabic CSS but that extra space is still their due to addthis button. So far i am not able to figure out what part of addthis is triggering this in arabic version

Comment: Superb You have gone into details. Thanks this has resolved my issue

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker its my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite at_a11y class in your style sheet as following :

```
.at_a11y {
    height: 1px !important;
    /*left: -10000px !important;*/
    left:0px !important; /* Change left attribute to resolve scrolling bug */
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: auto !important;
    width: 1px !important;
}
```